# Elasticsearch: Accessing IndexedScript in aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

ES offers the possibility to store your script within an internal index ( see [IndexedScript](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_indexed_scripts) ), but unfortunately I cannot access it from aggreagtions.

Creating the index:

```
POST /_scripts/groovy/termFrequency
{
  "script": "_index['textBody'][term].tf()"
}
```

Using the script within aggreagtions:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
   "query":{
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "aggs":{
      "tf_sum":{
        "sum":{
          "script": {
            "script": "termFrequency",
            "lang": "groovy",
            "params": {"term":"keyword"}
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

results in the syntax-error: `Parse Failure [Unexpected token START_OBJECT in [tf_sum].`

The purpose of the script is, to extract the term frequencies. I don't want to use `script_files`, because uploading such files is expensive in cloud services (e.g. found).

Comment: What version of ES you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for [ES 1.7](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/modules-scripting.html), you were looking at `ES 2.1`

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "tf_sum": {
      "sum": {
        "script_id": "termFrequency", <--- you access it with script_id
        "lang": "groovy",
        "params": {
          "term": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, i got confused with different versions of ES.